# What is the reason for new function tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2?

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

Tensorflow has a wonderful function.

> tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Later I see another function,

> tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2

what is the reason for this new function?

While using the earlier function Tensorflow says,

> Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow into
>   the labels input on backprop by default.
>
> See tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2.

I don't understand what it actually means. However the definition of the functions are same.

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
    _sentinel=None,
    labels=None,
    logits=None,
    dim=-1,
    name=None
)
```

The documentations are kind of over my head (As they are also kind of same). Any better explanation?

Comment: Thank @mikkola Yea it's a duplicate. Should I delete the question or just write an answer from those post.?

Comment: No need to make any changes, once it's marked as a duplicate that's sufficient because there's now a link to the original question.